# how to get only string type input in python

Tags: python

```
while guess_letter != temp[j]:
            guess_letter = input(f"what is the {j+1} letter in the given word: ")
            if len(guess_letter) > 1:
                print("enter only one letter at one time")
                break
```

I want to add feature to get only string type input in this code

Comment: Like `elif not ('a' <= guess_letter.lower() <= 'z'):`?

Comment: All inputs are strings?

Comment: As you used f-string, I guess you are using python 3.x, where all input are treated as string. If you are using python 2.x, use raw_input() instead of input() if you want to treat all input as string. And if you want to check for "alphabet" input instead of "string", use Tim's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your question!
i think you don't want numbers u only need letters
so for that. Use this to see if there are numbers
in your input

```
while guess_letter != temp[j]:
        guess_letter = input(f"what is the {j+1} letter in the given word: ")
        if len(guess_letter) > 1:
            print("enter only one letter at one time")
            break
        for i in guess_letter:
            if i.isnumeric:
                print('please enter letters not numbers')
                break
            else:
                pass
```

using a for loop will be best as it will check every latter in the string.
And you have a wrong concept for strings.
A string doesn't mean latter a string can be anything like 1234,!@#$%,ABCD,abc anything as soon as it is in between the two inverted commas ' ' or " " .

Comment: Thank you.I just forgot this   "A string doesn't mean latter a string can be anything like 1234,!@#$%,ABCD,abc anything as soon as it is in between the two inverted commas ' ' or " " ." .   You understood me correctly.